# Media Query for "Samsung Galaxy S6 and S7"

Tags: css, media-queries

Can you please let me know the media query for "Samsung Galaxy S6 and S7"?
 I google this a lot but couldn't find any place for them? 
Is there any website to have all new device like Samsung Galaxy S7 Media query information? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can target specific "screen resolutions" with media queries, but not specific devices.

To target Galaxy S6 and S7, you'll need to do this:

```
<style id="normal">
 body {
  //Default stylesheet
 }
</style>

<style id="galaxy">
 body {
  //Separate Stylesheet for Galaxy S6 or S7
 }
</style>

<script>
 var s = document.getElementById("galaxy"), n = navigator.userAgent;

 s.disabled = true; //Disable Stylesheet

 //Choose one of these:

 if(n.indexOf("SM-G92")!=-1||n.indexOf("SM-G93")!=-1) s.disabled = false;
 //includes Edge, Edge+

 if(n.indexOf("SM-G920")!=-1||n.indexOf("SM-G930")!=-1) s.disabled = false;
 //Does NOT include Edge, Edge+
</script>
```